# Adding partition to already partitioned table by not touching existing partition data

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, partitioning

I want to add new partitions to already partitioned table, this is straight forward if we use REORGANIZE as it's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437795/adding-a-partition-to-already-partitioned-table), but in my case, I have huge data in p_max partition which is taking forever to REORGANIZE.

So, I want to add new partitions to the already partitioned table without REORGANIZING the current p_max partition so that new partitions get added instantly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple:  always have `p_max` empty.  I like to call it `future`.  Then, just *before* you need `p_3`, split `future` into `p_3` and `future`.  With no data in that partition, it is fast.

Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint#high_level_view_of_the_code

The "Why":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint#why_

(Both are in the same treatise on MySQL Partitioning.)

**More**

What are you `PARTITIONing BY ...`?  (I can be less vague if I knew of your "BY ...".)

The best I can recommend is to take enough down-time to

```
ALTER TABLE ..
    REORGANIZE p_max to
        p_3 ... LESS THAN (...),
        p_4 ... LESS THAN (...),
        p_5 ... LESS THAN (...),
        p_max ... LESS THAN MAXVALUE;  -- empty
```

It may or may not be useful to have p_4 and p_5.  It is 'cleaner' to break the data into whatever pattern you have established (eg, monthly), but it may not provide any benefit.

Note that that can leave a new p_max that is empty.  Then, future reorgs can be fast.

As I note in my blog, `p_max` *should* always be empty, but if it accidentally gets filled with data, you won't be losing the data.  Instead, the reorg will be slower (as you are observing).

**Plan B**  *This may be your best hope.*

See the Percona Toolkit.  It has `pt-online-schema-update`, which, I think, will handle Altering a Partitioned table.

Comment: I cannot empty p_max now since its already filled with millions of records